# Benefits or uses for the Boolean.booleanValue function on Java?

Tags: java, boolean, wrapper, primitive

So, I've seen this line of code:

```
Boolean variable = false;
/* ..stuff.. */
if(variable.booleanValue() == false) {
/* ..more stuff..*/
}
```

And I've done, in a different place:

```
Boolean variable = false;
/* ..my stuff..*/
if(!variable) {
/* ..more of my stuff..*/
}
```

The question is: What is the difference/advantages of the first snippet of code over the first?

The long version is: Given I can use the Boolean variable as a primitive (boolean) one, what's the point on doing variable.booleanValue() and even comparing it to a boolean value? Doesn't this also introduces the risk (on the code impossible, but hey) of a null pointer exception if variable is not initialised?

There's any case in which is advisable using variable.booleanValue above just "variable"?

Comment: The risk of the null pointer exception is in the second snippet as well — only disguised, so one might consider it still worth. My taste is for the second, though. I thoroughly dislike comparing boolean values with `== true` or `== false`. And no, I can’t think of an example where I’d want to call `booleanValue()` explicitly.

Comment: As mentioned - your states here are using boxing/unboxing. Realistically its the same as Boolean val = Boolean.FALSE (or TRUE), which can be unboxed to a primitive state of true/false using the which is the same as calling the .booleanValue() on the Object - Big Boolean is useful if you want to state at all ie in web app radio buttons - Null, True/False  there are many others but thats the main one we use it for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no difference between the behaviour of the two snippets.

[JLS 5.1.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8):

> At run time, unboxing conversion proceeds as follows:
>
> If r is a reference of type Boolean, then unboxing conversion converts r into r.booleanValue()

So `if (variable) {...}` will execute as `if (variable.booleanValue()) {...}`. And because they're completely equivalent, they're both equally susceptible to NPE if `variable == null`.

This means that a possible minor advantage of the explicit call to `booleanValue()` is that you can instantly see that `variable` is being dereferenced, while with `variable == false` it is slightly less obvious.

Whether you add `== false` or a negation is a matter of taste, I prefer to avoid using the `==` operator to compare a boolean expression to `true` or `false`.

But I think it's more important that you avoid `Boolean` altogether and use the primitive type where possible.

Comment: + 1 as it mentioned the fact unboxing / boxing is being used to derive the Object Boolean from primitive state.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know that the booleanValue was autocalled (hence, I did not got what was the point of the function at all, as I thought it was some kind of low-level java magic). I try to avoid this kind of wrappers, but you know, inherited code I can't touch.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is auto unboxing.

The first version, which is better coded as:

```
if (variable.booleanValue())
```

does *not* require auto unboxing, so can be used with pre 1.5 versions of Java.

The second version, uses auto unboxing, and so requires version 1.5 and above.

If you need your code to run on and old Java version, you must use version 1.

Both can throw NPE, so there's no difference on that point.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that the only advantage of the first method over the second it´s the posibility to compile the code with older JDK's/ Java languaje specification prior to Java 1.5

Answer (score 3):

The [answer by Telcontar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36594796/3182664) points out the only thing that I can think of to *technically* make a difference: The second code snippet relies on [Autoboxing (or rather auto-unboxing)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html), and thus, requires Java version >= 1.5.

Apart from that, there is no technical difference. You mentioned

> Doesn't this also introduces the risk (on the code impossible, but hey) of a null pointer exception if variable is not initialized?

but this is the case for **both** versions. Even the second one will throw a `NullPointerException` when the variable is `null`.

---

However, I was curious about this one as well, and did a test:

```
public class TheManyShadesOfFasle
{
    public static int testBoxedBooleanBooleanValueComparison()
    {
        Boolean variable = false;
        if(variable.booleanValue() == false)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }

    public static int testBoxedBooleanComparison()
    {
        Boolean variable = false;
        if(variable == Boolean.FALSE)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }

    public static int testBoxedBooleanBooleanValueDirect()
    {
        Boolean variable = false;
        if(!variable.booleanValue())
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }

    public static int testBoxedBooleanDirect()
    {
        Boolean variable = false;
        if(!variable)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }

    public static int testBooleanComparison()
    {
        boolean variable = false;
        if(variable == false)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }

    public static int testBooleanDirect()
    {
        boolean variable = false;
        if(!variable)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }

}
```

This can be decompiled with `javap -c`, to obtain the bytecodes:

```
  public static int testBoxedBooleanBooleanValueComparison();
    Code:
       0: iconst_0
       1: invokestatic  #2                  // Method java/lang/Boolean.valueOf:(Z)Ljava/lang/Boolean;
       4: astore_0
       5: aload_0
       6: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/lang/Boolean.booleanValue:()Z
       9: ifne          14
      12: iconst_0
      13: ireturn
      14: iconst_1
      15: ireturn

  public static int testBoxedBooleanComparison();
    Code:
       0: iconst_0
       1: invokestatic  #2                  // Method java/lang/Boolean.valueOf:(Z)Ljava/lang/Boolean;
       4: astore_0
       5: aload_0
       6: getstatic     #4                  // Field java/lang/Boolean.FALSE:Ljava/lang/Boolean;
       9: if_acmpne     14
      12: iconst_0
      13: ireturn
      14: iconst_1
      15: ireturn

  public static int testBoxedBooleanBooleanValueDirect();
    Code:
       0: iconst_0
       1: invokestatic  #2                  // Method java/lang/Boolean.valueOf:(Z)Ljava/lang/Boolean;
       4: astore_0
       5: aload_0
       6: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/lang/Boolean.booleanValue:()Z
       9: ifne          14
      12: iconst_0
      13: ireturn
      14: iconst_1
      15: ireturn

  public static int testBoxedBooleanDirect();
    Code:
       0: iconst_0
       1: invokestatic  #2                  // Method java/lang/Boolean.valueOf:(Z)Ljava/lang/Boolean;
       4: astore_0
       5: aload_0
       6: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/lang/Boolean.booleanValue:()Z
       9: ifne          14
      12: iconst_0
      13: ireturn
      14: iconst_1
      15: ireturn

  public static int testBooleanComparison();
    Code:
       0: iconst_0
       1: istore_0
       2: iload_0
       3: ifne          8
       6: iconst_0
       7: ireturn
       8: iconst_1
       9: ireturn

  public static int testBooleanDirect();
    Code:
       0: iconst_0
       1: istore_0
       2: iload_0
       3: ifne          8
       6: iconst_0
       7: ireturn
       8: iconst_1
       9: ireturn
```

And one can see that the bytecode of `testBoxedBooleanBooleanValueComparison` and `testBoxedBooleanDirect` (corresponding to your first and second code snippet) are **identical**. (This basically means: The auto-unboxing is *implicitly* calling the `booleanValue` method of `Boolean` internally). The same for `if(!variable.booleanValue())`, as it can be seen in `testBoxedBooleanBooleanValueDirect`.

The other cases are mainly there for completeness: The `testBooleanComparison` and `testBooleanDirect` cases each have the same bytecode, but it differs from the other ones because there is no unboxing or derefencing taking place.

---

One case may be worth pointing out: A comparison of the variable to `Boolean.FALSE` or `Boolean.TRUE` can make sense, because it implicitly covers the case of the variable being `null`:

```
if (variable == Boolean.TRUE) {
    ...
} else {
    // Here, the variable is either "false" or "null"
}
```

vs

```
if (variable == Boolean.FALSE) {
    ...
} else {
    // Here, the variable is either "true" or "null"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Boolean` has three states - `true`, `false` and `null`. If you have in uninitialized then you will get `NullPointerException` in case of writing `!var`.
Also remember, objects are autoinitialized to `null` while boolean primitive to `false`.